# How to posting a tumblr photo post via Python script

Tags: python, tumblr

Here's the code that I'm using to send email with attachments via Python, but it does not work well with tumblr, basically, the email sent by the script went through okay, but tumblr does not recognize it as photo post, could anyone please kindly let me know how to fix it? Thank you so much,

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage

import smtplib
import os

user_name = 'username'
password = 'password'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'photo post via email'
msg['From'] = 'from@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'to@tumblr.com'

file_path = os.path.join('A_smile_a_day_keeps_the_pain_and_the_doctor_away.jpg')
fp = open(file_path, 'rb')
img = MIMEImage(fp.read())
fp.close()
msg.attach(img)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(user_name, password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and I got a post with just the text `'photo post via email'` but with no image.

I tested the following code and I got a post with the image and the text `'photo post via email'`.

```
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders

import smtplib
import os

user_name = 'username'
password = 'password'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'photo post via email'
msg['From'] = 'from@gmail.com'
msg['To'] = 'to@tumblr.com'

file_path = os.path.join('A_smile_a_day_keeps_the_pain_and_the_doctor_away.jpg')
fp = open(file_path, 'rb')
part = MIMEBase('image', 'jpeg')
part.set_payload( fp.read() )
Encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file_path))
fp.close()
msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.starttls()
server.login(user_name, password)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

The key point is to use `MIMEBase` instead of `MIMEImage` and then to properly encode the image and add a proper header.

My code is based on [auto_tumblr.py written by Petri Purho](https://github.com/gummikana/auto_tumblr.py).